# How do you run a batch transcode script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I need to batch transcode thousands of of .webm audio files to e.g mp3.

I found a script [here](https://gist.github.com/matthewberryman/f87ecaeba87684e950416eeeae7d6c78) which I could adapt to my purpose.

However, where do I run such a script?

Comment: You could consider [S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/batch-ops.html) with a lambda function. The function would run your code (after it gets adapted to lambda environment).

Comment: So, I take e.g that script I linked to, adapt it for my purposes, then I adapt that code to lambda environment and run it in S3 batch operations? In other words, that script adapted to my purposes would not work. There is a step to make it appropriate for lambda?

Comment: Yes, lambda function requires a [handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html). So you would have to add it to your code.

Answer (score 1):

That script uses [Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/introduction.html).

Basically, you first **create a pipeline** in Elastic Transcoder, which tells it where to find the input files. Then, you create a job by specifying the input file and the desired output format. The job then runs for a while and the output file appears in the nominated S3 bucket.

I suggest you try it manually in the management console first. You can then write a script to automate the job creation (similar to the one you linked).

The script can run *anywhere on the Internet*.

You can create a script like that with any programming language (eg Python) or you could use the AWS Command-Line Interface. See: [create-job — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elastictranscoder/create-job.html)

Comment: Thank you for answering me directly, I much appreciate it. I could even run the script locally then, right?

Comment: Yes. A simple way is to make an Excel spreadsheet with the name of the files. Then, create a formula that calls Elastic Transcoder and requests one file to be converted. Test it and, if it works, copy that formula for all other files, then paste it into a command window. (Requires the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to be installed.) Or, write a script in a programming language of your choice.